# How to get the loading time of an api inside angular 9 application

Tags: angular, time, loading

is there any way to get the loading time of an api which is inside angular.I am searching for the code to get the loading time of an api which is used inside the angular 9 UI

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.time('HttpCall');

this.http.get(url).then((response) => console.timeEnd('HttpCall'));
```

Or

```js
const startTime = new Date().getTime();

this.http.get(url).then((response) => console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime));
```

Or

```js
const t0 = performance.now();

this.http.get(url).then((response) => console.log(performance.now() - t0));
```

Comment: httpClient.get is an observable, not a promise

Comment: That `http` refers to the http library that is injected into service. Not anything specific.